# knitr hook to indicate child rmd status

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a hook in knitr that will indicate if the rendered chunk is a being run via the `child` argument? I want to skip some chunks in the child rmd when it is run as a child document.

Eg

`Parent.Rmd`

```
---
title: "My Analysis"
author: "My Name"
date: "1/23/2020"
output: html_document
---
​
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

​
{r,child='PATH_TO_CHILD.Rmd'}
```

`PATH_TO_CHILD.Rmd`

```
---
title: "My Sub Analysis"
author: "My Name"
date: "1/23/2020"
output: html_document
---
​
{r, eval = is_child}
 some r code that i dont want to run when this is a child

​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal knitr option that can be use to know if you are in child mode. It is `opts_knit$get("child")`. It should be `TRUE` when an Rmd is rendered in child mode and `FALSE` otherwise.
This value is set by knitr itself for the child document feature to work. This option should not be modified but I guess it is safe to read this option.